# I have a cube with data and a power BI report is generated out of that cube. Getting a DIV/0 ERROR

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, powerbi-desktop

I have a cube with data and a power BI report is generated out of that cube. I am getting a DIV/0 ERROR.

On the Freq/Sev tab, if a single slicer is chosen from “Dwelling limit banded” or “Construction Year band” the Frequency graph spikes to a minimum of 50%...as additional slicers are added, the Frequency spike increase exponentially.

The severity graph spikes to infinity if “Cat Status=Cat” is chosen along with certain other filers, especially if a northern “State Name” is chosen.

The severity hits infinity when “Catastrophe type=(anything other than hail-, wind-, or winter-storm)” regardless of other filters chosen.

The severity hits infinity when “Loss Cause Group=(earthquake or unknown)” regardless of other filters chosen.

Comment: This is a divide by Zero error. whenever you are getting this your is 0

Comment: I didn't get  you exactly Moaz. May I know what exactly to do in this case?

Comment: In your measure defination, you should check if the denominator is 0 then it doesnt calculate.

Comment: It's very difficult to advise on a problem with your code, when we can't see your code. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question, to make it clearer.

Comment: Did you try to adjust the measure as recomended?

Comment: NO I didn't I am pretty new to SSAS and Power BI I don't know how to do that. Would be great help if you can let me know.